Maximal cardinality of a subset of the powerset of $[n]$ on which the induced action of $S_n$ is $k$-transitive
A permutation $\pi$ of $[n]=\{1,...,n\}$ induces an action on the subsets of $[n]$ in the natural way ($\pi A = \{ \pi a : a \in A \}$). Given $k \ge 1$, let $T_{n,k}$ be the maximal cardinality that a subset $B$ of ${\cal P}[n]$ can have such that the symmetric group $S_n$'s induced action on $A$ is $k$-transitive, i.e., if $A_1,...,A_k$ are distinct members of $B$, and so are $A_1',...,A_k'$, then there is a $\pi\in S_n$ such that $\pi A_i=A_i'$ for $1\le i\le k$.
What is $T_{n,k}$?
Clearly, it's non-increasing in $k$.
If $k=1$, then the collection of all $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$-element (or $\lceil n/2 \rceil$-element) subsets of $[n]$ achieves the maximum cardinality $T_{n,1} = {n \choose {\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}$.
For $1<k\le n$, we have $T_{n,k} \ge n$ as $S_n$ is $n$-transitive on the singletons (or on the complements of singletons). I don't know how to improve on this bound.

If $k=2$, the question is equivalent to asking how many binary strings of length $n$ there can be with the same number of ones in each string and with all distinct pairs having the same overlap count (i.e., the same number of ones in the same position). I can't construct more than $n$, but it's not obvious to me that more than $n$ is impossible.

Theorem: $T_{n,1}={n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$. For $2\le k\le n$, we have $T_{n,k}=n$. For $n<k\le 2^n$, we have $T_{n,k}=k-1$. For $k>2^n$, we have $T_{n,k}=-\infty$.
Proof: For $k\ge 1$, all the subsets of $[n]$ in $B$ must have the same cardinality, and then we have $1$-transitivity. The peak number of subsets is achieved at cardinality $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ or $\lceil n/2 \rceil$. That proves the $T_{n,1}$ value.
Next suppose $k=2$ and let $S_n$ be $2$-transitive on $B$. Then any two elements of $B$ must have the same cardinality and any pair of elements of $B$ must have the same cardinality of overlap. Now we mimic the proof of Fisher's inequality (I am grateful to Daniel Herden for suggesting this method). Suppose $A_1,...,A_m$ are the members of $B$. Let $M$ be a matrix where $A_{ij} = 1_{A_j}(i)$ (where $1_X$ is the characteristic function of $X$) for $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le m$. Let $C=M^T M$.
Then $C_{ij}=|A_1|$ if $i=j$ and $C_{ij}=|A_1\cap A_2|$ if $i\ne j$. If these numbers are equal, then $m=1$, and in particular $m\le n$. Otherwise, $|A_1|>|A_1\cap A_2|$. Then $C$ is an $m$-by-$m$ combinatorial matrix, with non-zero determinant, hence of rank $m$. Its rank can't exceed that of $M$, which in turn can't exceed $n$. Thus, $m\le n$.
For $2\le k\le n$, the singletons are a set $B$ with cardinality $n$ and $S_n$ is $n$-transitive on them, so $T_{n,k}\ge n$. Since we also have $T_{n,k}\le n$ by the above, we have $T_{n,k}=n$.
Now suppose $n<k\le 2^n$. Trivially $T_{n,k}\ge k-1$ if $k\le 2^n$, since $S_n$ is trivially $k$-transitive on any subset of ${\cal P}[n]$ of cardinality less than $k$ (at least the way I defined $k$-transitivity). But there is no subset of ${\cal P}[n]$ of cardinality at least $k$ where $S_n$ is $2$-transitive by what was shown above, so all we can have is the trivial case of subsets of cardinality $k-1$. Thus, $T_{n,k}=k-1$.
Finally, if $2^n<k$, there are no $k$-subsets, so $T_{n,k}=-\infty$ (if we defined the maximum of $\varnothing$ as $-\infty$).
